# java how to determine logical expression minimum values to evauate

Tags: java, math, logical-operators

I have an expression (an example)

```
(value1<15 AND value2>25) OR ((value3>0 and vaue4<5) OR (value5<6 and value7>8))
```

The issue is value1-7 are calls to external services, which are expensive. And we need to reduce cost, so we need to make a minimum number of calls to evaluate this expression. For example if we have

```
(value1<15 AND value2>25)
```

evaluated to true, we don't need to evaluate right part, so we don't need to make useless calls to external services. How to determine in java (or may be just in math) when we need to stop, and further evaluations will not make any effect?

### UPDATE

I have 5 workers that works on 5 different servers.

first worker:

```
    accept(expression)
    value1=calculateValue1()
    setValueToExpression(expression, 0, value1)
    enough=expression.checkIsItEnough()
    if(!enough){
      determineNextWorker(expression)
      sendToNExtWorker()
    }
    else return expression.evaluate()
```

The second worker

```
    accept(expression)
    value2=calculateValue2()
    setValueToExpression(expression, 1, value2)
    enough=expression.checkIsItEnough()
    if(!enough){
     determineNextWorker(expression)
     sendToNextWorker()
    }
    else return expression.evaluate()
```

.....................

As I said in comments, I clearly understand that if we can write

```
 evaluator.evaluate("(value1<5 and value2>6) or (value3>5 and value4>7)")
```

it evaluates it as all of us know, but I don't have this ability due to many reasons. I also can't make it function calls value1()<15...
It's happening synchronously, one by one but even on different servers, kinda offline evaluation. Hope it's clear

Comment: This question will probably get closed for this reason: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: If you don't need to evaluate if (1<15 && 2>25), why isn't the rest inside an else statement?  Besides, AFAIK if the left-hand expression evaluates to true and the right is an OR, it isn't even looked at.

Comment: Thank you, but I do need to evaluate the entire expression. In my example if I evaluated (value1<15 AND value2>25) to true, I don't need to evaluate right part because true or false,  true or true are always true, so right part evaluation is useless, but expensive

Comment: In Java, if `a == true` in `a || b`, `b` is not evaluated anyway.

Comment: Thank you, I know that, bit as I wrote in comments below, in my case in expression (a>5) or (b>6) we should know in advance that value a is sufficient for evaluating the entire expression, because this expression should be evaluated on value-by-value basis, we can't get more that one value at once. Thank you

Comment: You're not making sense. 'We' don't 'know in advance' that value a is sufficient. We know when *when we evaluate it* and it yields `true`. There is nothing different about your situation. The Java operators already do exactly what you want.

Comment: Thank you, ok let me explain it the other way. in expression ((a>5) or (b>9)) or (c>7 and d<6)) we know only value of a and can't get other values. Should we know value of b? or if we have only values of a and b, should we know value of d, c? We can't just get and evaluate the entire expression, we only can do that part-by-part.

Comment: If the left operand of the || operator evaluates to true, the right operand isn't evaluated. If the left operand of the && operator evaluates false, the right operand isn't evaluated. This is exactly want you say you need. Try it with function calls instead of variables and see for yourself which ones are and aren't called.

Comment: Unclear what you're asking. You 'can't evaluate it for many reasons' such as what?

Comment: it's a long story, I just need to know when to stop to prevent additional useless calls. I need to put it in chain as I wrote

Comment: As I can see, there is already a test made by calling the checkIsItEnough() method, so the next worker is not blindly started by default. On the other hand, the logic behind that method is a different story.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider normal short-circuit intermediate code for:

`(value1<15 AND value2>25) OR ((value3>0 and value4<5) OR (value5<6 and value7>8))`

```
if value1<15 goto value2_test else goto value3_test
value2_test:
if value2>25 goto success else goto value3_test
value3_test:
if value3>0 goto value4_test else goto value5_test
value4_test:
if value4<5 goto success else goto value5_test
value5_test:
if value5<6 goto value7_test else goto fail
value7_test:
if value7>8 goto success else goto fail
```

You could simplify things substantially by having a tree representation of your expression, and passing around subexpressions represented by trees rather than the whole expression.

For example, the first worker would have two subexpressions: `value2>25` and `(value3>0 and value4<5) OR (value5<6 and value7>8)`. Select the first one if the test succeeds, the second one if it fails.

The value2>25 worker would have two subexpressions: "success" and `(value3>0 and value4<5) OR (value5<6 and value7>8)`

I am not aware of any library to do the conversions. If it exists, it would be in the domain of compiler construction.

I would try very hard to change this to something where one worker could organize the job, and simply call on other workers to evaluate one relational condition.

========================================================================
More detail, because this seems to be the sort of answer the OP is looking for:

Terminology:

- "term" -> A comparison or Boolean variable, such as `value2>25`
- "product" -> The AND of some Boolean expressions
- "sum" -> The OR of
  some Boolean expressions.

Consider only sum-of-products expressions, such as `(value1<15 AND value2>25) OR ((value3>0 and value4<5) OR (value5<6 and value7>8))`. This is not a very significant limitation. Many optimizations and simplifications used in digital logic design depend on converting arbitrary logical expressions to sum-of-products.

At each step, the worker for the leading term of an expression is called. Depending on the expression and the outcome of its test, it can declare success, declare failure, or calculate a new expression that must be passed to the worker for its leading term.

```
   if this worker's condition is true
     if more terms in current product
       remove the leading term from the current product
       pass the new expression to the worker for the next term
    else
       declare success
  else
    if there is another product
      remove the leading product from the expression
      pass the new expression to the worker for the new leading product's leading term
    else
      declare failure
```

Answer (score 3):

A standard condition will work that way (short circuit) because it will only evaluate the expressions if necessary (if the first part of an `||` condition is true it won't evaluate the rest):

```
if ((value1() < 15 && value2() > 25) || (value3() > 0 && vaue4() < 5) ...)
```

Note that I have replace the values by method calls - if you precalculate each value of course it won't work...

Examples:

- if your condition `value1() < 15` returns false, then `value2()` won't be called
- if the first condition `value1() < 15 && value2() > 25` is true, `value3()` and `value4()` won't be evaluated.

---

**References:**

See [JLS #15.23](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.23) (emphasis mine):

> The conditional-and operator `&&` is like `&`, ***but evaluates its right-hand operand only if the value of its left-hand operand is true***.

Similarly in [JLS #15.24](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.24):

> The conditional-or operator `||` operator is like `|`, ***but evaluates its right-hand operand only if the value of its left-hand operand is false***.

Comment: Thank you, I know that, but in my case value1-7 are going one-by one, I have no ability to take all of them simultaneously, so for example first 'worker' takes this expression, calculates value1(), but it's not responsible for calculating value2(), etc), it need to check that value1() is sufficient for evaluating the entire expression. If not, it passes expression to worker2, which calculates value2() and checks the expression, and so on, if workerN checks that value1()-valueN() are sufficient, it shuld evaluate the expression and stop.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand - you should provide more details in your question (actual code would be ideal)...

Comment: Thank you, sorry if I explained it not clear.but the issue is I have a chain or workers and I have only one new value for this expression at any moment. Please check out http://pastie.org/10239293

Comment: thank you, but again, I have no ability to evaluate the entire expression, I just can't. I can't call evaluator.evaluate(expr). If I could, you're would be true, but I can't I can't have functions that called value1() and so on. It's a chain in my case. I perfectly understand what are you talking about, but the issue is I can't evaluate the entire expression at once.

Comment: @avalon your description is unclear - you should edit your question with a simple but complete example that reproduces your problem to get better answers.

Comment: The entire expression *isn't* evaluated at once. Operands in a Java expression are evaluated one by one, left to right, and evaluation ceases when a result has been obtained.

Comment: thank you, sorry I will edit my question, but I meant that I can't do evaluator.evaluate(expression), I need to bring it through a chain when every chain node only responsible for one particular value. And the node should decide to go further or not. thank you

Comment: If your workers evaluate one expression at a time, and in your specific logic the expressions are linked by an implicit/explicit `OR` condition, then you should stop at the first worker that evaluates its expression to `true`. Best case scenario is when you stop at the first worker, worst case is when everything is `false` and all workers evaluate.

Comment: thank you, but my condition may be too long and complex, it may be just any, I don't need to know about it, I just gave a couple of examples

Answer (score 0):

Conditional logic by default evaluates the least amount of conditions needed to obtain an evaluation result. This is not specific to Java. This is how things work. Also, the grouping parentheses are completely optional in your case.

Depending on your use case, you may want to push forward inside the condition the expressions that are most likely to be true. And perhaps consider caching for a certain amount of time some of the results, if applicable.

Comment: This is not 'how things work', it is how the && and || operators work, in C and C++ and Java. It is rather specific. It was invented by John Mcarthy and first used in some form in Lisp.

Comment: Guys, I perfectly understand your concerns, but it's nothing to do with my case. In y case I can't evaluate the entire expression at once, I need a function isItEnoughToEvaluate(expression, array of values), minimum set of values for expression when I can say that all others are redundant. That's it. I mean values from the beginning of expression. Ideally, evaluate first value, then determine the second, etc.

Comment: @avalon On the contrary. You haven't  perfectly understood a single word you've been told here.

Comment: @EJP: Things, in this context, are the `AND` and `OR` conditional operators, irrespective of any specific notation. So, yes this is how things work in the implementation of most high-level programming languages, not just the ones you mentioned.